# jQuery tooltip append content in bottom of the page

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tooltip

I am using a jQuery tooltip. The tooltip appears in the correct place; It appears and disappears in the correct moment. Everything seems to work correctly.. BUT
When the toltip appear, the content appear ALSO in tne bottom of the page and it does not disappear anymore. Here my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).tooltip({
        items: "#img_help_easypay",
        show: {
            effect: "slideDown",
            delay: 250
        },
        content: function () {
            return "<span>Title</span><br />" +
                   "<p>" +
                   "   <span>bla bla bla</span><br />" +
                   "   <span>bla bla bla.</span>" +
                   "</p>"
        }
    });
});
```

Where `img_help_easypay` is

```
<img id="img_help_easypay" src="/Styles/img/info.png" alt="aiuto easypay" style="vertical-align:top" />
```

Non js error...  Can anyone help me? Thank you..

EDIT: In bottom of page the div has role="log"

Answer (score 2):

According to this ticket from the jQuery UI bugs platform, this is a feature started in jQuery UI 1.11.0 to increase accessibility : http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/10689

If you want to entirely remove the appended `<div>` from your code, you have to destroy the tooltip :

```
$(document).tooltip( "destroy" );
```

Comment: $(document).tooltip("destroy"); worked perfectly for me. My scenario was that I had a custom tool tip method applied to input criteria search fields, however, after the "OK" / "Submit" button was clicked the custom tool tip format persisted into a new html page ~ and I could not get the the tool tip on that new page to "disappear" unless I did a full page refresh. I added $(document).tooltip("destroy"); at the end of my "OK" / Submit button logic.

Answer (score 2):

This is an accessibility "feature". I just hide the created divs:

```
 .ui-helper-hidden-accessible {
    display:none;
}
```